# Mean.js Multiple Layouts, Server or Angular Layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I've been developing a  mean.js application. I have an admin theme that I'm trying to integrate with the existing application.

My question is

1. Can we have multiple Server Layouts, ? If the logged-in user is Regular User, use layout-1 if the user is Admin use layout-2
2. If we cannot have multiple server layout (I presume it isn't possible). Is there any way to detect the params or scope variable in the Angular Client App and dynamically load a partial inside the main Layout.

Let say I have an Index.html file, if the intended route is Dashboard, I just replace a section of the page view, ( Ruby on Rails Developers would know this)

**UPDATE 1** :
I've created 2 files with my required Admin Index, and Layout files.

```
admin.index.server.view.html
```

and

```
admin.layout.server.view.html
```

I've also added the following code in my core.server.routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
   // Root routing
   var core = require('../../app/controllers/core');
   app.route('/').get(core.index);
   app.route('/admin/').get(core.adminIndex);
};
```

I've also added the following code in my core.server.controller.js

```
exports.adminIndex = function(req, res) {
   res.render('admin.index', {
       user: req.user || null
   });
};
```

and when I hit localhost:3000/admin/ I get Error: Cannot find module 'index'

Comment: What view engine are you using on the server? How much server-side rendering are you doing, generally? Is it a single page app or more 'standard' just enhanced w/ angular?

Comment: Hi, I'm using the standard Mean.js Stack, Also its a single Page application. I don't have server side render, they are all angular routes and views. but I want to have two seperate server Index files, to separate assets from each other.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the two view files from `admin.index.server.view.html` and `admin.layout.server.view.html` to `admin-index.server.view.html` and `admin-index.server.view.html` respectively.

Also, change this line in your `core.server.controller.js` file;
`res.render('admin.index', {`

to this;
`res.render('admin-index', {`